# Jquery multilevel list problem in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-sortable

first of all sorry about my English...

Well, I try to create a sortable list of questions/answers and it works perfectly in FF but not in IE. In IE, when I try to sort an answer (second level li) the its question and the same group answers moves together with the selected question in a strange way.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eFDWw/17/)

If you have any idea please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add this code as well and it should work

```
$('.answer').mousedown( function(e){ return false; } );
```

This will stop the bubbling effect of the mousedown event to reach the parent element that is also sortable.

Same thing can be accomplished with

```
$('.answer').mousedown( function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); } );
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/eFDWw/20/

Comment: Good job, I was looking in the `.sortable()`'s options... No clue about this.