# jQuery Sortable - Multilevel problem in IE

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, jquery-ui-sortable, multi-level

I've got a question about using sortable in a multilevel list.

In a CMS I'm using jQuery UI sortable to order my menu items. The system works in all browsers, but in IE it won't work. I've made a standalone version where you can see the problem: http://hhwcms.nl/temp/
When you try to order a sub menu you get the problem, the parent item will follow your mouse. In Firefox I can just drag the sub item, but in Internet Explorer the parent will follow.
I've posted my source code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/GE7s10GU

Hopefully could somebody help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the brief answer but I'm just on my way out of the door. Have you tried using .live() to bind to the events? I had a problem in jQuery with IE and switching over to .live() seemed to help.

Comment: I've founded the same problem on Stackoverflow and that anwser helped me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333387/jquery-multilevel-list-problem-in-ie

Comment: Ok great, glad you sorted it.